# Getting Error of Angular is not defined & Uncaught Error:No Module in type Script Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have implemented a code where i stuck with this problem.
Problem 1:- Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
Problem 2:-Uncaught Error: No module: CustomerSearch

I have written my code:-

and  here is my view page

```
<view>
   <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="QuickSearch.ascx.cs" Inherits="CustomerSearch.QuickSearch1" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>

    <html >
    <head id="Head1" >
       <script src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/Contoller/QuickSearchController.js"  />
        <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/Interface/module.js"  />
       <%-- <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/app.routes.js"  />--%>

        <title></title>


        <script type="text/javascript">





        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="CustomerSearch">
    <form id="form1" >
    <div>



    <div id="page"  ng-controller="CustomerCtrl as custom">

              <div id="menuleftcontent">
         <table>
                 <tr id="menu">
                               <td width="25px !important;"><input type="text" id="txtActId" value="Search" class="tftextinput2" ng-model="search.txtActId" />  </td>
                               <td><input type="button" value="Search"  class="tfbutton2" data-ng-click="search(search)" /> </td>

                         </tr>
                  <tr id="TableRow1">
                      <td colspan="2">
                          <asp:DropDownList ID="listCustomerType" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" Width="194px" Height="27px" ng-model="search.listCustomerType">

                          </asp:DropDownList>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td colspan="2">
                     <input type="checkbox" id="checkActiveOnly"  class="NormalTextBox" value="Active Customers Only" ng-model="search.checkActiveOnly" />Active Customers Only
                    <br>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="checkParentsOnly" class="NormalTextBox" value="Parent Accounts Only" ng-model="search.checkParentsOnly" />Parent Accounts Only


                 </td>
             </tr>
            </table>

     <div >

    <div>
        <div>
```

Comment: try moving `module.js` after `angular.js` file

Comment: @pankajparkar code edited,Go through the new code

Comment: @RadimKöhler no only this error occurs again and again and din get any answer which help me .Not able to find where m i wrong

Comment: @Mico, really would like to help, but not sure if I can.. Anyhow, I tried to show how we can face some issues, errors, with plunkers ...hope it will give at least some insight...

Comment: and getting one more error of No module: ngRoute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce this kind of issue, we can either

1) "remove" angular script reference, or
2) just place it at the very **"late"** position, after our modules.

There is [a broken plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w2HJAPE5v18qjbitWRA4?p=preview) which will provide us with this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

because we skipped angular script

```
<!--<script data-require="angular.js@*"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"
  ></script>-->        

<script src="MainApp.js"></script>
<script src="CustomerSearch.dirc.js"></script>
```

The same issue *(with many other errors)* we would face, if we place *angular* in the page too late *(after our module definition)*. Check this [broken example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ei9MdlhZkj1YPgPtT3L9?p=preview)

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(anonymous function) @ MainApp.js:1
>   Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'CustomerSearch' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

This lines were the culprit:

```
<script src="MainApp.js"></script>

<script data-require="angular.js@*"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"
  ></script>  

<script src="CustomerSearch.dirc.js"></script>
```

In case, that all is properly ordered in page, it will work (this is [WORKING plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ThygCFqpxiN1BZ7GYG1f?p=preview)):

```
<script data-require="angular.js@*"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"
  ></script>  
<script src="MainApp.js"></script>
<script src="CustomerSearch.dirc.js"></script>
```

These are standard issues with that kind of error...

Also, in case we get

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'CustomerSearch' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

That could be caused by wrong placement of our [own scripts](http://plnkr.co/edit/iOdZnLEYnhqk7tONrH7g?p=preview):

```
<script data-require="angular.js@*"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"
  ></script>  

<script src="CustomerSearch.dirc.js"></script> 
<script src="MainApp.js"></script> // this one should be before the other one
```

because MainApp.js defines modules:

```
var app = angular.module('MainApp', [
  'CustomerSearch'
  ]);

angular.module('CustomerSearch',[])
```

And the CustomerSearch.dric.js uses them

```
var app = angular.module('CustomerSearch');
```

so, we need the declaration to happen first

EXTEND:

This code snippet from the question:

```
<html >
<head id="Head1" >
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/app/Contoller/QuickSearchController.js"  />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/app/Interface/Interface.js"  />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/Scripts/angular.js"  />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/Scripts/angular.min.js"  />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/app/app.routes.js"  />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/app/app.module.js"  />
    <script src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Should be (I guess) reorganized:

```
<html >
<head id="Head1" >
    // THIS MUST be first
    <script src ="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    // MODULES must be defined first    
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/app/app.module.js"  />


    // the rest most likely could be as is
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/app/Contoller/QuickSearchController.js"  />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/app/Interface/Interface.js"  />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/Scripts/angular.js"  />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/Scripts/angular.min.js"  />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/app/app.routes.js"  />
```

Comment: Kohler I have updated my reference in my question please review it. and is there any other problem ? have u seen my code?

Comment: I observed your update.. and tried to order it as I expect it should be. Check my extended anwwer. Hope it will help. ALSO, please, read my answer. I showed you scenarios... with errors. that could help you to avoid such issues later.. please, take your time and check it.

Comment: Kohler done with resolving some error but now getting error of Unknown provider: $controllerProvider from CustomerSearch

Comment: That's a great progess ;) this kind of error means, that such controller is missing in any of the modules, referenced by main module... Could you shoe me full error (e.g. update your quesiton)

Comment: Kohler Please View  image in my question

Comment: I created new plunkers, new examples and added another answer describing the latest issue (with controller). Hope it will help. That would be all from me, because I would say that now you should have all info about these issues. Good luck, sir

Comment: Enjoy Typescript with angular, sir ;)

Answer (score 2):

I believe `module.js` contains angular controller code, then it is using angular objects while creating different components.

`module`.js should be moved after `angular.d.ts` file

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of files should be **jquery**, then **angular** then your **module** file.

Explanation: First you declare **jquery**, which is an independent library.

Second, you include **angular** which is also independent, but since you are using it with jquery, you want angular to know that jquery is available so that angular can utilize the power of jquery.

Third comes your **script** because it should be parsed when it has already parsed angular(since then only your angular code makes sense)

**UPDATE:**

1. You need to define the module as

   var CustomerSearch  = angular.module('module_name')

   and store it in some variable before you use it. I cannot see this your code(I might be wrong since I don't know typescript(or whatever you used syntax) but you can check that the variable is defined or not)
2. Now, the file where you did this should be at the top of all your JS files after jQuery and angularJS. That will make define your module before you try to use that.

Comment: I made some changes in code please check @TheJugadGuru

Comment: I don't know about typescript, but both the errors you specified are due to order of scripts. Please check

Comment: i done with that still the same error is there...@TheJugadGuru

Comment: I have modified the answer with more things, but I am having trouble understanding the syntax. Its like shooting in the dark, hoping you hit the target :)

Answer (score 1):

Unknown provider almost always means: we forgot to register our controller(provider).

That error is related to our setting

```
<div ... ng-controller="CustomerCtrl" ...
```

There is [a broken example](http://plnkr.co/edit/EjQRQP7eLeFnLA2CUx96?p=preview) - which will give us this kind of error:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'CustomerCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

So, what is wrong in our code:

```
module CustomerSearch.controllers {
    var app = angular.module('CustomerSearch');

    export class CustomerCtrl {
        // ...
    }
    //app.controller("CustomerCtrl", CustomerSearch.controllers.CustomerCtrl);
}
```

There is missing call **`app.controller("")`**

This [WORKING plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cs5QkVyMlNrHFy5PyYJT?p=preview) has this def:

```
module CustomerSearch.controllers {
    var app = angular.module('CustomerSearch');

    export class CustomerCtrl {
        // ...
    }
    app.controller("CustomerCtrl", CustomerSearch.controllers.CustomerCtrl);
}
```

And *(once we registered controller to our app)* there is no error when we use `search.aspx` with this line:

```
<div id="page"  ng-controller="CustomerCtrl as custom">
```