# AngulaJs + TypeScript: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, typescript, typescript1.4

I am trying to use Type Script + Angular Js.I have declared my controller and interfaces.But when i trying to run my system it will through and error of

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module .

I have read all but not able to get whats the exact problem is:-
I have mentioned my code below:-

My View Page

```
        <html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"> </script>
     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/Customer.New/Scripts/angular.js" />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/Customer.New/Scripts/angular.min.js" />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/Customer.New/app/app.routes.js" />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/Customer.New/app/app.module.js" />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/Customer.New/app/Controller/CreateCustomerController.js" />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/Customer.New/app/Interface/Interface.js" />

    <title>Create Customer</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-app=" CustomerNew">
        <div id="page" style="width:90% ! important;" data-ng-controller="CreateCustomerCtrl as custom">
```

[image: Please See Exception Here]

Comment: Can you post the complete exception message?

Comment: @mxa055 have posted the completed exception ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this error byb making changes into the declaration of my ng-app as i have declared my ng-app before my form tag but now i made changes and removed the div declared before form tags and apply it as:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Scripts/angular.js" />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/app/app.routes.js" />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/app/app.module.js" />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="app/Controller/CreateCustomerController.js" />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/app/Interface/Interface.js" />

    <title>Create Customer</title>
</head>
<body>
       <form data-ng-app="CustomerNew" data-ng-controller="CreateCustomerCtrl as custom" name="form" class="css-form" novalidate >
```

Answer (score 3):

The real issue (not sure if only) is that we hide/redefine module definition. Once we do:

```
var app = angular.module("CustomerNew", ['ngRoute']);
```

and next/*previously*

```
var CreateCustomerapp = angular.module("CustomerNew", []);
```

we can/must define module only once, and then only ask for it via **getter**:

```
// firstly create
var app = angular.module("CustomerNew", ['ngRoute']);
...
// later get it
// var CreateCustomerapp = angular.module("CustomerNew", []); // setter
var CreateCustomerapp = angular.module("CustomerNew"); // getter
```

Comment: Good catch, didn't even see it down there :D

Comment: @Radim Kohler it means i have to make changes in my controller as
var CreateCustomerapp = angular.module("CustomerNew", ['ngRoute']);
Right?

Comment: I would say YES. The module should be loaded first.. create module... the Controller JS should then just ask for module and extend it.. hope it helps...

Comment: @Mico I would say that I spotted another issue... Please, check it, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Another issue could/would be the **order** of scripts loading into page. This is the current *(not working)*:

```
<head>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js" ></script>     
     // angular is not in play yet here   
     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/app/app.module.js" />
     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/app/Controller/CreateCustomerController.js" />
     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/app/Interface/Interface.js" />
     // too late....
     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Scrpts/angular.js" />
     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Scrpts/angular.min.js" />
     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/app/app.routes.js" />
     ...
```

We should use this definition order:

```
<head>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js" ></script>     


     // ANGULAR First
     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Scrpts/angular.js" />
     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Scrpts/angular.min.js" />
     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/app/app.routes.js" />

     // angular is now ready to start solve app
     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/app/app.module.js" />
     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/app/Controller/CreateCustomerController.js" />
     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/app/Interface/Interface.js" />
     ...
```

After update ... there is 3 times defined angular:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"> </script>
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/Customer.New/Scripts/angular.js" />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/Customer.New/Scripts/angular.min.js" />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/Customer.New/app/app.routes.js" />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/Customer.New/app/app.module.js" />
    ...
```

this is not good (maybe working but not good) it should be just once

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"> </script>
    // just once
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/Customer.New/app/app.routes.js" />
    <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/DesktopModules/Customer.New/app/app.module.js" />
    ...
```

All code now should be loaded in the correct order. But because it is throwing error... the other problems I can see is content of **`Module.js`**

```
// this is typescript
((): void=> {
    var app = angular.module("CustomerNew", ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(CustomerNew.Routes.configureRoutes);
})()
```

that should be compiled:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("CustomerNew", ['ngRoute']);
    app.config(CustomerNew.Routes.configureRoutes);
})();
```

And MOSTLY, we need `UI-Router`, not **`ngRoute`**:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("CustomerNew", ['ui.router']);
    app.config(CustomerNew.Routes.configureRoutes);
})();
```

The 'ui.router' must be injected into main module. Check [that example](http://plnkr.co/edit/w2HJAPE5v18qjbitWRA4?p=preview) ... with all really running

Comment: Kohler i have tried the same but it produces more errors of angular is not defined and more because as u have seen my previous questions the current order was given by you only and it's working fine.Is dre any other option to get rid of it?

Comment: The fact that it produces more errors, does not mean that my suggestion is wrong. Mico, please recheck this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30590960/1679310 - as you would see - that `<script>` order is 1) ANGULAR 2) module definition (with a setter of dependencies) 2) the other JS stuff, using module getters **Please** check twice my last code snippet with these comments: 1) // THIS MUST be first 2) // MODULES must be defined first  3) // the rest most likely could be as is... I am consistent, would you agree?

Comment: I am agree with you but as i have seen in the link of my previous question too that i have defined the same than what the problem ? and i have defined in the same way as u told me before

Comment: I tried to do my best to read issues from your code snippets. It is hard to guess what else is wrong... but if you will take [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w2HJAPE5v18qjbitWRA4?p=preview) .. which is working and has correct order and does load controller (angular, module and finally controller with directive).. you should make it. Or create your plunker.. which is almost working.. and I can help... *but I would say - in my answers here you should have all solved...*

Comment: Hope I will be able to create it but i think i can't because for creating it have to convert my whole code in HTML as right now i m using asp.net server tags.And as per me your suggestion are alws helpfull for me.

Comment: What are the latest errors.. if you changed the order as I asked you? Could you update your answer with latest code and latest error? (or create new, to get larger audience than me...)

Comment: Hope now you will get even closer. But really,you should do that yourself.. observe my working example and compare all small details... This should be done on your side... to be in future able to improve that all... *and a note, my name is Radim, Family name is Köhler*

Comment: Kohler i solved this problem by declaring ng-app in form as previously i have declared it before form tag

Comment: That sounds great, does not it? ;) ;) I am really happy ;)

Comment: Mico, good luck... That is amazing ;) enjoy mighty Angular with Typescript